# Authenticate to Azure Sql Database without Active Directory? I Don't have SQL admin credentials either

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

I have learned a very painful lesson a that you cannot authenticate to Azure SQL database using Active Directory in the Cloud using  Custom .Net activity.

At this point I'm looking for alternatives.

The code I'm using is:

```
    string constring=
          "Server = server,1433; " +
          "Initial Catalog =dbname; " +
          "Persist Security Info = False; " +
          "MultipleActiveResultSets = False; " +
          "Encrypt = True; TrustServerCertificate = False;" +
          " Authentication = Active Directory Integrated";


 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
 con.Open()
```

Which fails in when deployed. I get an "unable to load asadsql.dll" error.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using framework 4.7.2, is there anyway around this?

Comment: The Azure SQL Database instance will need to be set-up for Azure AD before you can access that instance using AD credentials: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure

Comment: If and when the above has been set-up, you can connect using Azure AD identities: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication#connecting-using-azure-ad-identities (Please ensure you read the Additional considerations section).

Comment: @MikeUbezziMSFT Thanks Mike, Will Try this I'm a little skeptical, why does this work on my laptop but fails when deployed in the Cloud ADF V2?

Comment: Azure Data Factory supports AAD authentication for Azure SQL Database via service principle and via managed service identity: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-data-factory-supports-aad-authentication-for-azure-sql-database-and-sql-data-warehouse/

Comment: @mikeUbezziMSFT just so I understand correctly, since it's in and adfv2 I can't use activate directory as stated in your first comment, instead I should use Service principle or msi?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. As your last comment stated ADFv2, I was initially providing the instructions for adding a service principle to your Azure SQL Database but, with ADF in the picture, you can use either service principle or managed service identity per the instructions stated.

Comment: Hi @MikeUbezziMSFT just wanted to give you an update, we tried creating a Service account and I'm still getting this error. My understanding is that .dll is needed when running it from a client machine https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#active-directory-password-authentication-1 but how do i get it to work once in the cloud? Any guidance appreciated

Comment: I am looking into this.

Comment: Do you have an Integration Runtime in the mix? This, I believe, is the missing piece: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime. The following Blog discusses this, in that there is a Json file that brings together the Service Principle ID, Service Principle Key, Target SQL Database...under what is called a Linked Service: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-data-factory-supports-aad-authentication-for-azure-sql-database-and-sql-data-warehouse/

Comment: Hi Mike, I can run a hello, world windows desktop console app. I can also run a console app that pings SharePoint apis, which I needed to add dlls to. I'm assuming I have a runtime setup because these are successful in running and I see the default runtime is reference in our setup.  The only part I can't get to work is connecting to the azure SQL database using c# active directory password method.

Comment: Do you have an Azure Support Plan? If not, I can have a one-time incident ticket created to have this looked at. Please send an email to AzCommunity at Microsoft.com with your Azure Subscription GUID and I will send you further instructions. With an incident ticket created, we have a better view of all your services. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run your SQL/AAD app successfully from your laptop and can connect to SQLDB, you should be able to run it from the Web app. I am slightly confused about ADF in this scenario